# Reading Files with a double pointer and malloc

Tags: c, file, pointers, malloc, 2d

So, i am making the **Game of Life** of Conway.I  want to read a file and save it in a double pointer and malloc it's memory but i am getting a crash in codeblocks.
In the world i will put the dead and the living cells.

```
**world = (char **)malloc(grammes * sizeof(char));
for(i=0;i<grammes;i++)
    world[i]=(char *)malloc(stiles * sizeof(char));


for(i=0;i<grammes;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<stiles;j++)
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%c",&world[i][j]);
    }
}

for(i=0;i<grammes;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<stiles;j++)
    {
        printf("%c",world[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Can you please post [mcve]?

Comment: Sample input, expected output?

Comment: Where do you declare the variable "world"?

Comment: The very first code line should probably be using `sizeof(char*)` because the third line is setting its elements to pointers.

Comment: @nabil.douss The var world is an universal variable.. I have declared it outside the fuction.

Comment: @WeatherVane Still codeblocks crashes when i compile&run it... It crashes when it enters at the first for.

Comment: @AchilleasGuru.: SHow the full code.

Comment: It is impossible to store the contents of a file of any appreciable size in a pointer (including a pointer to a pointer).  You may, however, be able to store the file contents in the object(s) to which the pointer points, or in other, even more indirectly-specified objects.  Yes, I am in part nitpicking your wording, but it is important to understand the distinction between a pointer and the thing to which it points, and many questions around here hinge on a failure to understand it.  Yours may be one of them, in fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. By `**world`  you access the actual value and not the address. You have to change it to `world` ( If you have already declared the variable)
2. In the first line it should be `sizeof(char*)` because world is a pointer to an array of char*

Answer (score 1):

Reason for crash is that `world` is double pointer and you should allocate memory for `world` first not for `**world`.

Replace below statement

```
  **world = (char **)malloc(grammes * sizeof(char));
```

with

```
 world = malloc(grammes * sizeof(char*)); //since world is double pointer it should be sizeof(char*)
```

Note : Typecasting of `malloc` is not required as suggested here [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @chux I suggested the same

Comment: Tip: use `world = malloc(sizeof *word * grammes);`  It is easier to code, review and maintain.  No need to trying to get the type right.

Answer (score 1):

Well the thing is - you asked the question to misguide us not to help us to help you.

```
char ** world = malloc(..);
```

This is ok.

When you did this before `char** world;` and then you do this

```
**world = ...
```

Wrong. Because you have used a `char` to store the value of a pointer.

Well now see what you did, instead creating a chunk of memory which contains multiple `char*` you allocated for `char` then again used each of them to store the address of memory where `char` will be stored. Yes wrong it is

```
world = malloc(sizeof(char*) *grammes);
```

Better

```
world = malloc(sizeof *world * grammes);
```

And `malloc`'s return value should be checked and `malloc` returns a `void*` which can be implicitly converted to `char*` no need to cast the result.

```
world = malloc(sizeof *world * grammes);
if( world == NULL ){
    perror("malloc failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Check the return value of `fscanf` also. You can check the man pages or standard to know their success value that hey return.

---

`chux` points out -

There are few more things but it is not sure if you will be engage in such details

`malloc(sz)` *may* return `NULL` if `sz = 0` So saying `malloc` returns `NULL` means error is not perfectly correct or even if the `sz` is an overflown value then also it might return `NULL`.

Here it is better to write the check like this

```
if( world != NULL && grammes != 0){
   //Error.
}
```

Comment: A pedantic note to your good answer: `if( world == NULL ){` is not necessarily a "malloc failed".  Consider  if `grammes == 0`, a return value of `NULL` is OK. `malloc(0)` is one of those implementation defined corner cases.  I'd use `if( world == NULL && grammes != 0){` Another corner is `sizeof *world * grammes` overflowing.  Yet such details are certainly beyond OP's present concern.

Comment: @chux.: Yes those are the nice corner points - Yes that's why safest would be to check the size first - because on size 0 malloc *may* return NULL...will add it as note.

Comment: @chux.: but again here shouldn't the check be `grammes > 0`? Ofcourse if it `size_t` then assigning `negative` will always results in true to this.

Comment: OP did not specify the sign-ness of `grammes` unfortunately.  `grammes != 0` appeared safer as we lack the "sign-ness" info.   With an _unsigned_ `grammes`, then either `grammes != 0` or `grammes > 0` function the same.  `grammes > 0` is more clear in that case.